# How do we achieve AAR in android for lower version

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I was going through [AAR](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) to find out how we can redirect to Play Store if the app not installed. It working for fine. According to the document it says that AAR introduced in Android 4.0 (API level 14). I even changed my android target version to 2.3 and **`createApplicationRecord`** method is not supported. How do i achieve AAR similar function in lower version. Any kind references or sample code or links or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can read this :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p

Comment: The NFC device that is receiving the beamed data must support the com.android.npp NDEF push protocol or NFC Forum's SNEP (Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol). The com.android.npp protocol is required for devices on API level 9 (Android 2.3) to API level 13 (Android 3.2). com.android.npp and SNEP are both required on API level 14 (Android 4.0) and later.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9235090/1202968